# How to copy and rename a solution under source control in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a VS2013 solution called ShoppingService.sln with 7 projects under TFS source control.
Now I want to make a copy of the solution, rename it to 'BasketService.sln' and have it under source control again.
I don't want to make branches of the original solution, since both solutions should co-exist separate from each other.

What's the quickest or best way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

Ok, here's what I ended up doing:

1. Copy entire solution folder to new location.
2. Remove any source control files. They begin with *.vs.
3. Remove any read-only attributes on folders and files.
4. Open solution from new folder and rename solution and each project.
5. Open properties for each project and edit assembly name and default namespace.
6. Close solution.
7. Rename folders on disk.
8. Edit solution file in a texteditor. Replace all references with new folder names, and remove team foundation section in .sln.
9. Open solution again in VS and fix any leftover issues. I use Resharper to fix new namespaces.
10. Search through all files for your old solution/folder name and update with new name
11. Consider deleting the obj and bin folders to force Visual Studio to regenerate all of those files during a build
12. Add solution to source control again.

And you're done.

Answer (score 4):

Step 8a. Open all Project files (e.g. .CSPROJ, .projitems) in a text editor and edit folder pathnames to point to the new solution's folders.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest

File --> save solution As. `'BasketService.sln'`

Right Click Solution --> Add to source control.

Right click Solution --> Check In

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't accomplish what I'm trying to achieve. I want full renaming on all projects in the solution as well. The problem is the old solution is still bound to source control, and it can't just be renamed. I tried renaming .proj files and psysical folder names on each project, but VS then fecthes the old folders back, so I end up with fourteen project folders instead of seven.