# How to clone a solution in VS2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution MySolution.ABC.sln with 2 projects MySolution.ABC.Hello1.csproj and MySolution.ABC.Hello2.csproj in my TFS.
Name spaces are MySolution.ABC.Hello1 and MySolution.ABC.Hello2.

I need to clone this solution with another name like MySolution.XYZ.sln with same 2 projects with names changed to MySolution.XYX.Hello1.csproj and MySolution.XYZ.Hello2.csproj.Name spaces also should change to MySolution.XYX.Hello1 and MySolution.XYZ.Hello2.

Is there any way for this?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duğlicate of - [http://stackoverflow.com/a/26571130/2794280](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26571130/2794280)

Answer (score 4):

May be there are some shorter ways to do that, but I usually do it in this way:

- In file explorer, make a copy of the solution.
- Rename the copied folder as MySolution.XYZ
- Rename the folders of projects inside the solution folder as MySolution.XYX.Hello1 and MySolution.XYZ.Hello2
- Open the copied solution in Visual Studio
- With the mouse right click, remove references to the projects
- With the mouse right click, rename the solution to MySolution.XYZ (this will rename *.sln file)
- With the mouse right click, add existing projects (MySolution.XYX.Hello1 and MySolution.XYZ.Hello2) to solution
- With the mouse right click on the projects, rename the projects (this will rename *.csproj files)
- With F2 click on namespace, rename it with a new name.
- With the right mouse click on the projects, select properties and set the default namespase